# How to separate HTML/XML Tags in PHP Array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and need to split parameters. So far I have tried:

```
$test = array
(
    'username' => 'vale',
    'apiaccesskey' => 'myapi',
    'action' => 'placeimeiorder',
    'requestformat' => 'JSON',
    'parameters' => '<PARAMETERS><CUSTOMFIELD>bnVsbA==</CUSTOMFIELD><ID>221</ID><IMEI>354443063506889</IMEI><MODELID></MODELID><PROVIDERID></PROVIDERID><NETWORK></NETWORK><PIN></PIN><KBH></KBH><MEP></MEP><PRD></PRD><TYPE></TYPE><LOCKS></LOCKS><REFERENCE></REFERENCE><SN></SN><SECRO></SECRO></PARAMETERS>',

    'version' => '2.3.1'
);



$html = $test['parameters'];
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);     
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('PARAMETERS');    
echo 'ID '.$tags->item(0)->getAttribute('ID').'" IMEI="'.$tags->item(0)->getAttribute('IMEI').'"/>';
```

In return I get Fatal Errors with this Code, but it seeme it recognizong and separating **Tag** values and this is what want. Here is error log:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Tag id invalid in Entity, line: 1 in /test.php on line 24

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Tag imei invalid in Entity, line: 1 in /test.php on line 24

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Tag modelid invalid in Entity, line: 1 in /test.php on line 24

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Tag providerid invalid in Entity, line: 1 in /test.php on line 24

....
```

---

The OUTPUTs I want in Array:

```
'CUSTOMFIELD' = 'bnVsbA==',
'ID' = '221',
'IMEI' = '354443063506889',
'MODELID' = '',
'PROVIDERID' = '',
'NETWORK' = '',
..so on..
```

So I can use `echo $test['IMEI'];`and it will output: **354443063506889**

How can I resolve this error and get all Tags separated in `$test['parameters']` ?

Thank you for helping.

Comment: can you post output you want?

Comment: `loadHTML()` is meant for HTML. Since your input is XML, please use `loadXML()` instead.

Comment: @DishaV. Updated my question.

Comment: @Ultimater: tried that now, error gone, but info is gone too :(

Comment: @Cyborg see my updated answer for all element in array format

Answer (score 2):

It seems `parameters` is xml so you should use `loadXML` function, see example below:

```
$test = array
(
    'username' => 'vale',
    'apiaccesskey' => 'myapi',
    'action' => 'placeimeiorder',
    'requestformat' => 'JSON',
    'parameters' => '<PARAMETERS><CUSTOMFIELD>bnVsbA==</CUSTOMFIELD><ID>221</ID><IMEI>354443063506889</IMEI><MODELID></MODELID><PROVIDERID></PROVIDERID><NETWORK></NETWORK><PIN></PIN><KBH></KBH><MEP></MEP><PRD></PRD><TYPE></TYPE><LOCKS></LOCKS><REFERENCE></REFERENCE><SN></SN><SECRO></SECRO></PARAMETERS>',

    'version' => '2.3.1'
);

$html = $test['parameters'];
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($html);
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('ID');
$id = $tags->item(0)->nodeValue;
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('IMEI');
$imei = $tags->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo 'ID="'.$id.'" ,  IMEI="'.$imei.'"';
```

To get all element in array you can use below solution:

```
$html = $test['parameters'];
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($html);
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('PARAMETERS');

$root = $doc->documentElement;
foreach($root->childNodes as $node){
    $attributes[$node->nodeName] = $node->nodeValue;
}

print_r($attributes);
```

Comment: Nice solution, works exactly as I want :) Thank a million!

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want: (full working example)

```
<?php
$test = Array
(
    'username' => 'vale',
    'apiaccesskey' => 'myapi',
    'action' => 'placeimeiorder',
    'requestformat' => 'JSON',
    'parameters' => '<PARAMETERS><CUSTOMFIELD>bnVsbA==</CUSTOMFIELD><ID>221</ID><IMEI>354443063506889</IMEI><MODELID></MODELID><PROVIDERID></PROVIDERID><NETWORK></NETWORK><PIN></PIN><KBH></KBH><MEP></MEP><PRD></PRD><TYPE></TYPE><LOCKS></LOCKS><REFERENCE></REFERENCE><SN></SN><SECRO></SECRO></PARAMETERS>',

    'version' => '2.3.1'
);



$html = $test['parameters'];
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($html);     
$p = $doc->getElementsByTagName('PARAMETERS')->item(0);
$opts=array();
foreach($p->getElementsByTagName('*') as $item)
{
    $opts[$item->nodeName]=$item->nodeValue;
}
echo '<pre>'.print_r($opts,true).'</pre>';
```

Comment: Nice solution, works exactly as I want :) Thank a million!

Answer (score 0):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML('...');
libxml_clear_errors();
```

To ignore the Warnings, put use `libxml_use_internal_errors(true)`; before `loadHTML()` function.